# How to use the packages with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages) for loading js scripts simply using `firebug console`.

If I try the following code it works:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://127.0.0.1/~myName/myPublic/js/lib/require.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);

setTimeout(function() {
    require(["lib/jquery-1.7.1"], function() {
        console.log("test: ", $.fn); // **** it gives me the expected result *****
    });
}, 1000);
```

Now I would like to load all the js files present in http://127.0.0.1/~myName/myPublic/js/lib/

```
setTimeout(function() {
    require.config({
        "packages": ["lib"]
    });
    require(["lib"], function() {
        console.log("test: ", $.fn);
    });
}, 1000);
```

but I get the following error:

```
 Load timeout for modules: lib http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

What is wrong about the code using `require.conf`?

P.S.:
I run the code from http://127.0.0.1/~myName/myPublic/js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used require.js before, but something caught my eye - how would require.js on the client side know to fetch every *.js file in your directory?

Looking at the documentation, looks like require.js automatically loads a "main.js" if you specify the package.  Thus, it will look for http://127.0.0.1/~myName/myPublic/js/lib/main.js.  Furthermore, according to your config, it may additionally look for http://127.0.0.1/~myName/myPublic/js/lib/lib.js

If you really want to see how it works, try installing a packet sniffer like wireshark or charles.  See what sort of requests the client (browser) is making to search for the javascript files.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix your config -- the documentation on require.js for packages seems to be straight up wrong or I'm just not following it correctly.

Comment: Wireshark and Charles are overkill for this problem, simpler development tools like Firebug or the firefox console will show you the HTTP requests made by the browser.